# SAP HANA VORA AMI

Tags: hana, vora

I didn't get the AMI URL when I registered for the free HANA VORA. I got a 'Access your free HANA VORA' email from SAP, but it did not have the AMI in it.

Whom should I get in touch with to get this information?

Please help!
Thanks
PJ

Answer (score 1):

It seems the link on the email is broken somehow. But after signing up at [here](http://go.sap.com/cmp/syb/crm-xu15-int-voratrdm/index.html), It will lead you to [this page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9M8zP.png). The link "SAP HANA Vora Developer Edition on AWS" is valid here.